# Confusion on Capybara "Matchers"

Tags: rspec, capybara

So I usually see around 3-4 different examples when "asserting" text for instance.

The capybara docs even mention more than 1

`assert_text('foo')`

`page.has_text?('bar')`

`page.should have_content('baz')`  (Which apparently have_content is the same has have_text)

`expect(page).to have_content('boop')`

So...thats 4 different ways of checking the same thing. I know the `expect` is an rspec matcher...but what about the rest? What SHOULD I be using? The Capybara docs unfortunately don't go into the difference between them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert_text('foo')` is an assertion generally for use with minitest.

`page.has_text?('bar')` is just a method that returns true or false.  You would use this if you wanted to change behavior based on the presence or lack of presence of text on the page.  Not used very often when testing an app since you should know what to expect on the page and not need to perform different behavior based on the content.  Can be useful if automating/scraping though.

`page.should have_content('baz')` (Which apparently have_content is the same has have_text) -  As you stated - have_text is an alias for have_content so you can use whichever you prefer.  `have_content` is an RSpec matcher and would only be used when using RSpec. `should` is the old RSpec syntax which required patching the `should` method onto every object and has since been superseded by `expect`

expect(page).to have_content('boop') - current RSpec syntax

So if you're using the minitest test framework use the `assert_xxx` style methods, if using RSpec you could use either the `expect` style or the `should` style, although for anything new you probably want to be using `expect` style.